# Can AUCROC curves be used to evaluate forecasting results for time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, testing

I have built a time series forecasting model based on RNN.

Can I calculate AUCROC on the test set and the actual predicted values?

Example:

```
true_value = [1, 3, 23, 5, 8, ...]
model_predicted_value = [2, 4, 18, 6, 11, ...]
```

If it is possible how should I calculate the AUCROC curve?

Comment: Is your task regression or classification?

Comment: That is regression task

Comment: Then you cannot use AUROC, which is a classification metric. Please do not accept the incorrect answer that was posted, as it is misleading other people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUROC and ROC curves are metrics for classification. Since you seem to have a regression tasks, it does not make any sense to use a classification metric, it simply would give you incorrect results since they do not measure what you actually want.

So do not use AUROC for regression tasks, only for classification tasks.